# Exclude specific JS file from Webpack transpilation, but include in bundle

Tags: webpack, vue-cli, babel-loader

I have a very large JS file `pleaseExcludeMe.js` that is already minified and transpiled included in my vue project, which is using the default webpack setup.

I want to exclude that file from Webpack transpilation/transformation, **but is is needed in the bundle obviously**.

That file is imported by `Rooms.vue`.

This is my project structure:

```
root
  src/
    views/
      rooms/
        Rooms.vue
        pleaseExcludeMe.js  
  package.json
```

In my `vue.config.js`, I already tried this:

```js
configureWebpack: {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /pleaseExcludeMe/,
                loader: 'null-loader', // also tried 'dumb-loader'
                exclude: /pleaseExcludeMe/, // this seems to exclude the file from the bundle
            },
        ],
    },
},
```

How can I exclude that specific file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

```js
const path = require('path');

// ...
rules: [
  test: /\.js$/,
  exclude: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/views/rooms/pleaseExcludeMe.js'),
  ],
]
```